# After using this query category by products showing but my website design gone

Tags: php, html, css, laravel

When I use this query without passing any `category_id`, the design works perfectly.
But If I try to pass `category_id` to get the Products by Category, my design looks like this.

I am a beginner level Laravel programmer. I am trying to build an e-commerce website. Same code working if I want to show only products. But is doesn't work if I pass the id.

### Controller

```
class ShowCategoryController extends Controller
{
   public function Show_category($category_id)
   {
      $category_by_product=DB::table('tbl_products')
         ->join('tbl_category','tbl_products.category_id','=','tbl_category.category_id')
         ->join('tbl_manufacture','tbl_products.manufacture_id','=','tbl_manufacture.manufacture_id')
         ->select('tbl_products.*','tbl_category.category_name','tbl_manufacture.manufacture_name')
         ->where('tbl_products.product_id',$category_id)
         ->limit(6)
         ->get();
      $manage=view('Pages.cate')
         ->with('category_by_product', $category_by_product);

      return view('layouts.new')
         ->with('Pages.cate',$manage);
   }
}
```

I know my design and page are working. But I am sure if I made a mistake in my query. I will be glad if anyone help me.

Comment: maybe there is an error on your query thats why it is not showing? can you check your `storage/logs/laravel.log`?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please consult https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask for guidance how to improve your question. Please also try to use an appropriate typesetting for code.

Comment: `->where('tbl_products.product_id',$category_id)` i think on this part you need the product_id not the category_id thats why it didn't show?

Answer (score 0):

as I check your code, you have a syntax error on your `join()` please check on `->>join('tbl_category','tbl_products.category_id','=','tbl_category.category_i>d')` and
`->>join('tbl_manufacture','tbl_products.manufacture_id','=','tbl_manufacture.manufacture_id')` maybe that cause the error and shows nothing because you dont have error reporting enable on your server

Comment: this is my first time to ask any questions in StackOverflow that's why i don't know how to add the code.....I have no syntax error in my code....when i run the code only contents are showing but the design are gone...by content i can see that in my website category by product are showing but design is not there.

Answer (score 0):

I think error in this line `->where('tbl_products.product_id',$category_id)`

you should you that `->where('tbl_products.category_id',$category_id)`

for get products in this category

your error because you write **tlb_products.product_id** 
 and this is wrong, true is **tlb_products.category_id**

Comment: Yes i think my problem is that line... but i try so many way but cant find any solution....if i pass my id and write my code then this happened....is there any other way that i can show my category by product.

Comment: please try to change tbl_products.product_id  to  tbl_products.category_id

Comment: I changed it but nothing happens. :-(. Its still the same problem.